# Postmark PHP Demo Errors

Tags: php, email

I'm building a PHP script using the postmark inbound email function - and the demo PHP code is throwing all manner of errors for me. I've copied the code almost word-for-word from the demo page, but the \ seem to be causing PHP errors. [Demo code homepage is here](https://github.com/jjaffeux/postmark-inbound-php)

And the code I'm using:

```
require_once '/postmark/Autoloader.php';
\Postmark\Autoloader::register();

// this file should be the target of the callback you set in your postmark account
$inbound = new \Postmark\Inbound(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Errors:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/path/page.api.email.php on line 10

Line 10 is:     \Postmark\Autoloader::register();

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're probably not running PHP >= 5.3 - [Namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) (\Postmark\Autoloader) are only supported in >= 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require_once '../postmark/Autoloader.php';
\Postmark\Autoloader::register();

// this file should be the target of the callback you set in your postmark account
$inbound = new \Postmark\Inbound(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```